# How to get excel to recognize <20 as the number 20 without removing the "<"?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have mass amounts of lab reports with <20 mg/L results. I am trying to take the Geomean of a column of numbers EX. <20, <20, <20, 20, 1400, 2500, <20, <20. 
I noticed when i take the "<" away the geomean changes. How do i trick excel into thinking its a real number?

Comment: If it's less than 20, won't you change the results if you make it exactly 20?

Answer (score 3):

Try this **array formula**:

```
=GEOMEAN(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A6,"<","")))
```

This formula does everything in one shot. No `IF` statements, no dragging formulas down. It loops through A1 to A6, substitutes any "<" with a blank, takes the value, then takes the geomean of the resulting values.

All you have to do is replace `A1:A6` with whatever range you want the geomean of.

**Important**: To use an **array formula**, you need to type in the formula, then press:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>

(If you just press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it won't work.)

If you do this correctly, braces `{ }` will appear around your formula, like this:

```
{=GEOMEAN(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A6,"<","")))} // don't type in the braces, they will appear automatically
```

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Hey Dan-

If if helped you should mark as answered. I've upvoted as well.

Comment: @guitarthrower, I think you meant @frustrated with Excel, not me (if only I had the power to mark my own answers :)), but thanks for the vote :)

Comment: There I checked marked it!

Comment: @fustrated lol not uh.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom cell format.

Comment: Custom cell formats done work. And no it wont change the results, but we have to be able to see that it was detected at less than 20.

Comment: can you be more clear. What about custom cell formats doesn't work? I can see why they wouldn't, but by not being specific you're not helping find a better answer.

Comment: @guitarthrower, let me take a crack at answering this. Custom cell formats won't work because they only change the way data *looks*, not what the data actually *is*. So, even if you could make `<20` look like `20`, the `GEOMEAN` formula would still see it as a non-number and ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a formual in another column that either reads the value directly or takes the value part if there is a "<".

Adding a 0 or custom cell format will change the Geomean.

**EDIT**

Assume you have "<20" in A1

In B1 write: =MID(A1;1;1)
In C1 write: =IF(B1="<";20;A1)

The answer in C1 should now be 20. If you change A1 to 5 then C1 should change to 5.

Comment: How would i go about creating the formula?

Comment: Use the @IF function

Comment: I know to use an IF function. But how. I never understood IF Functions..i tried a few i found online but i couldnt get them to work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming
Your Data is in ColumnA and starts in row 1
Numbers <20 range average out to 10, so wherever there is <20

Then the formula in column b is
=IF(A1="<20",10,A1)

and drag the formula down the same number of rows as the data in column A.

Or to change the numbers in place in column A use Edit-->Replace to change all the <20 to 10